# Some questions about how jquery selectors traverse the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I know what traverses the DOM and what doesn't?

```
$('div p')
```

It seems like this returns all the div elements AND THEN does another scan for P elements on each dom element that was returned in the first div search.

```
$('div .foo')
```

The class ones don't seem to scan the dom. They only filter the previous list $('div') for elements that contain classes foo. If a child of $('div') has class foo it is not selected.

```
$('div, div')
```

Doesn't contain dupes. So it seems to be scanning only once with a list of lambdas that either compare or they don't. But this gets really really confusing when you have filters like :contains('x') which seem like they can recurse the dom on their very own.

So how do these selectors work? Does 'div .foo' traverse for only divs first and then do a filter for classes that contain foo, or does it somehow get turned into a computation that says when tag==Div && class==foo. What about when there's multiple selectors? They show up in the order they appeared on the page without dupes making me feel like it only scanned the dom once. Maybe it just sorts and removes dupes before returning?

Comment: Technically, what `$(div .foo)` does is look for all `.foo` elements, and THEN filter those that are `div`.

Comment: As far as unique results go - have a look at https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L40.

Comment: @mblase75 NO !! It check all class foo in DIV elements !

Comment: What it *actually* does is throwing a syntax error :)

Comment: @pimvdb All right, Mr. Know-It-All, so I forgot my quote marks. :-)

Comment: @TeChn4K Nope, the Sizzle selector engine [actually works from right to left](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/about-selectors-right-to-left) (unless there's an `#id` on the left), but the end result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery optimises it's selectors based on what is quickest. If there is a native browser supported method for getting an element (getElementById etc) it will use it, otherwise it will filter based on the results of the natively supported methods.